# How to get result from two different post types' meta boxes?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

I want to retrieve result from two different custom post type.I queried for `tax_query` , `meta_query` and another `meta_query` but retriving no result.there should be one result.

### Below is the codes,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'listings',
    's' => get_query_var( 's' ),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
        ),
    'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
        ),
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
);

    if(isset($_GET['city']) && !empty($_GET['city'])){
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'city',    
                'field' => 'slug',    
                'terms' => $selected_city,    
                'relation' => 'OR',
            ),
        );
    }
    if(isset($_GET['cuisine'])){
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'cuisine',    
                'field' => 'slug',    
                'terms' => $selected_cuisine,    
                'relation' => 'OR',
            ),
        );
    }
    if(isset($_GET['st'])){
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'restaurent_location',
                'value' => $location,    
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
        );
    }
    if(isset($_GET['has_takeaway'])){
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'has_resturent_takeaway',
                'value' => $takeaway,    
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        );
    }
$arg2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'reviews',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
    ),   
);
if(isset($_GET['rating_range'])){
    $args2['meta_query'][] = array(
        array(
            'key' => 'review_rating',
            'value' => array( $rating_range[0], $rating_range[1] ),    
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    );
}


$query = new WP_Query( array_merge($args, $args2) );
```

Answer (score 0):

get_query_var( 's' ) should be just $s after you've set $s. Right now it's not searching for anything.